# Guide on signing and packaging a Chromium build in MacOS

Tags: macos, chromium, code-signing-certificate

Currently, I'm trying to distribute my Chromium build in MacOS environment. However, the [documentation](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/chrome/installer/mac/signing/) from Chromium is not that well-defined to me, so I'm not sure how to do it right.
So in general, which steps do I need to be aware of when trying to sign and package Chromium in MacOS?

Currently, their documentation is talking about Chrome, not Chromium build. So I'm not sure that the documentation is what I need.

Comment: Are you trying to digitally sign all the files or jus the installer?

Comment: @Asesh Sorry I'm not sure what you mean since I'm not familiar with MacOS. I intend to sign the `.dmg` file. Is that what signing means in the Chromium documentation?

Comment: Then you can create an installer and If you plan the sign the dmg file only then you use can `codesign` tool in macOS to do so. It's similar to `signtool` for Windows, which is used to code sign binary files. But it's recommended to code sign all the binary files.